# Zxing scan clarfication

Tags: android, zxing

I am currently trying to develop an app with a QR scanner feature, in order to do this i have followed a few tutorials on how to implement it im having some problems.

Trying to make a button that will call upon the scanning feature and i am having a problem.
    Button button;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v.getId()==R.id.scan){
            //scan

                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }


        }

    });

}
```

This is what i am using to call upon the command but on the line
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
Its chucking me back an error saying that the constructor is undefined

I got my source code for the "IntentIntegrator" And "IntentResult" from [here](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/?r=2260) if you want to look at and if it.

And just a quick side question as far as i believe i am not allowed to change any of the source code, Is this true?

Thanks in advance, Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way. You need to pass current `Context` to the `Constructor`.

```
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(your_activity.this);
```

Comment: I thought i had already tried that but must of overlooked a spelling mistake, Thanks.

Got any clue on the second side question?

Comment: @Sparky There is no issue on your side question.I think it's ok.

Comment: Is there anything i have to put in place to say that it has been modified like in the copyright?

Answer (score 1):

please pass MainActivity context instead of Onclick context.

```
1)IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
```

or

```
2)IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(context);
```